Can't ping server from home network but mobile data works
I have a server at my vacation house. It used to work perfectly fine until a few days ago when I noticed I can't access it from my home network, but if I disable Wi-Fi and connect with mobile data it works. However, pinging the home IP from the server works. How is this even possible? The link between the networks must be good since I can ping the home IP from the server.

Sounds like somewhere in between, your ipaddress is blocked, or the wifi has blocked certain ports.
